# Changing a property of the inheriting class

Tags: swift, inheritance, cocoapods

I have a `class` that change the look and feel of the original text field and `inherit` from `UITextField`

```
class UINewTextField: UITextField{
    //Do some stuff with the text field here 
}
```

Now I am using some `pods` in `object-c` that have some `textfields` on it (the code in `swift` would look like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var textField: UITextField   
}
```

I have want to `inherit` this `ViewController` but I want to also change the `classes` of the `textFields` from `UITextField` to `UINewTextField`

```
class MyViewController: ViewController{
    ???
}
```

Is it possible?

So far I have been going to the code in the `pod` and changing directly there but everytime I run the the command to update the `pods` the files get change back to the original.

Comment: no, this is not possible. If UINewTextField inherits from UITextField, you should be able to assign it to UITextField via down casting and check when you use it if it in-fact is a UINewTextField.

Comment: @TheCodingArt Are you sure about that? I know it is possible in object-c

Comment: No, it is not possible in Obj-c. You cannot dynamically change class assignments without swizzling in Obj-c and that involves changing class mappings which is something you should avoid doing at all cost.

Comment: In Object-c is easily done because textFied is a pointer however in Swift it is not, but it must have a way to account for that

Comment: @lcaro, in obj-c that's tricking the compiler and is not 'easily' done. It's not knowing what you're doing XD. In Swift it works the same exact way. You downcast or upcast to a UITextView, which is exactly how you would do this in Obj-c. Being a pointer has nothing to do with it and everything in Swift is a pointer. You don't change the class of the actual property/variable, but you use inheritance to assign the classes. You're able to assign a UITextField pointer to anything that is or inherits from UITextField. Same with any class via textField = myNewTextField as UITextField in Swift.

Comment: In Obj-c if you override the property with a different class that inherits from the class of the property you're overriding, when you assign the value it just automatically downcasts or upcasts the property for you. In Swift you have to be explicit. If in Obj-c you change it to another class that doesn't inherit from your property... it will cause issues.

Comment: @TheCodingArt I did many times in object-c, create a new variable and point the old to the new, because they inherit from each other they fit perfectly, however in swift I can't find any info about it. No casting involved

Comment: @lcaro, that's really bad practice in Obj-c and I encourage you to stop doing that and to know what's really happening under the hood. Once again, in swift you would just downcast the value you're assigning via textField = myNewTextField as UITextField.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89210/discussion-between-icaro-and-thecodingart).